# How can I subtract 11:00pm from 1:30am without getting 9:30 as the result, in C#

Tags: c#

I've been trying to do this and I keep getting 9:30 when it should be 2:30. I want the difference in time between 11:00pm and 1:30am. I'm trying to make a program to help me keep track of working hours, but when I try to subtract time, it's done wrong. Some values are right and some are very wrong.

I'll post my class cause the main is only GUI and calling methods from this class:

Go all the way down to a method called `workedHours` or `calc1stPeriod`, this were I do my time calculations. They both basically do the same, but in different places.

```
class timeManager
{ private DateTime dt2,
        dt3,
        dt4,
        dt;

    //gets time for the 1st in
    public void getTimeIn(TextBox inTxt, Button outB, DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        //this tries to put the hours parsed in the variables. If it's wrong, goes to catch
        try
        {
            ArrayList timeSplitted = new ArrayList(); // holds time (text) splitted

            string[] splitTime = inTxt.Text.ToUpper().Split(':');

            // adds splitted time to arraylist if there's an M in any split that index by spaces. Input format: 8:00 pm
            for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.Length; i++)
            {
                timeSplitted.Add(splitTime[i]);

                if (splitTime[i].Contains("M"))
                {
                    string[] splitAm = splitTime[i].Split(' ');

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[0]);

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[1]);
                }
            }

            // delete cause it's a duplicate of the last 2 indexes
            timeSplitted.RemoveAt(1);


            //date well organized
            string a = dtp.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Year.ToString() + " " + timeSplitted[0] + ":" + timeSplitted[1] + " " +
                       timeSplitted[2];

            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(a);

            outB.Enabled = true;
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry", "Error!");

            inTxt.Focus();
        }
    }

    //displays total worked hours
    public void workedHours(TextBox totBx)
    {
        TimeSpan tota1,
        tota2,
        final;

        tota1 = dt.Subtract(dt2);

        tota2 = dt3.Subtract(dt4);

        final = tota1.Add(tota2);

        totBx.Text = ("Days:" + Math.Abs(final.Days) + " Time:" + Math.Abs(final.Hours) + ":" + Math.Abs(final.Minutes)).ToString();
    }

    //gets time for the 2nd in
    public void getTimeIn2(TextBox inTxt2, Button outB2, Button calcB, DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList timeSplitted = new ArrayList();

            string[] splitTime = inTxt2.Text.ToUpper().Split(':');

            for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.Length; i++)
            {
                timeSplitted.Add(splitTime[i]);

                if (splitTime[i].Contains("M"))
                {
                    string[] splitAm = splitTime[i].Split(' ');

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[0]);

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[1]);
                }
            }

            timeSplitted.RemoveAt(1);

            string a = dtp.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Year.ToString() + " " + timeSplitted[0] + ":" + timeSplitted[1] + " " +
                       timeSplitted[2];

            dt3 = Convert.ToDateTime(a);

            outB2.Enabled = true;

            calcB.Enabled = false;
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry", "Error!");

            inTxt2.Focus();
        }
    }

    //gets time for the 1st out
    public void getTimeOut(TextBox outTxt, Button inB2, Button calcB, DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList timeSplitted = new ArrayList();

            string[] splitTime = outTxt.Text.ToUpper().Split(':');

            for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.Length; i++)
            {
                timeSplitted.Add(splitTime[i]);

                if (splitTime[i].Contains("M"))
                {
                    string[] splitAm = splitTime[i].Split(' ');

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[0]);

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[1]);
                }
            }

            timeSplitted.RemoveAt(1);

            string a = dtp.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Year.ToString() + " " + timeSplitted[0] + ":" + timeSplitted[1] + " " +
                       timeSplitted[2];

            dt2 = Convert.ToDateTime(a);

            inB2.Enabled = true;

            calcB.Enabled = true;
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry", "Error!");

            outTxt.Focus();
        }
    }

    //gets time for the 2nd out
    public void getTimeOut2(TextBox outTxt2, TextBox resuTxt, DateTimePicker dtp)
    {
        try
        {
            ArrayList timeSplitted = new ArrayList();

            string[] splitTime = outTxt2.Text.ToUpper().Split(':');

            for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.Length; i++)
            {
                timeSplitted.Add(splitTime[i]);

                if (splitTime[i].Contains("M"))
                {
                    string[] splitAm = splitTime[i].Split(' ');

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[0]);

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[1]);
                }
            }

            timeSplitted.RemoveAt(1);

            string a = dtp.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Year.ToString() + " " + timeSplitted[0] + ":" + timeSplitted[1] + " " +
                       timeSplitted[2];

            dt4 = Convert.ToDateTime(a);

            workedHours(resuTxt);
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid entry", "Error!");

            outTxt2.Focus();
        }
    }

    //reset everything to default values
    public void reset(TextBox txt1, TextBox txt2, TextBox txt3, TextBox txt4, TextBox txt5, Button btn2, Button btn3, Button btn4)
    {
        txt1.Text = "";

        txt2.Text = "";

        txt3.Text = "";

        txt4.Text = "";

        txt5.Text = "";

        btn2.Enabled = false;

        btn3.Enabled = false;

        btn4.Enabled = false;
    }

    //calculates hours on the 1st period
    public void calc1stPeriod(TextBox resultTxt)
    {
        TimeSpan finalDt = dt - (dt2);

        if (Math.Abs(finalDt.Days) >= 1)
        {
            int finalHours = Math.Abs(finalDt.Days) * 24;

            resultTxt.Text = (Math.Abs(finalDt.Hours) + finalHours + ":" + Math.Abs(finalDt.Minutes)).ToString();
        }

        else if (finalDt.Hours > 12)
        {
            resultTxt.Text = (Math.Abs(finalDt.Hours - 12) + ":" + Math.Abs(finalDt.Minutes)).ToString();
        }

        else if (finalDt.Hours < 12)
        {
            resultTxt.Text = (Math.Abs(finalDt.Hours) + ":" + Math.Abs(finalDt.Minutes)).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution:**

```
ArrayList timeSplitted = new ArrayList(); // holds time (text) splitted

            string[] splitTime = inTxt.Text.ToUpper().Split(':');

            // adds splitted time to arraylist if there's an M in any split that index by spaces. Input format: 8:00 pm
            for (int i = 0; i < splitTime.Length; i++)
            {
                timeSplitted.Add(splitTime[i]);

                if (splitTime[i].Contains("M"))
                {
                    string[] splitAm = splitTime[i].Split(' ');

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[0]);

                    timeSplitted.Add(splitAm[1]);
                }                    
            }

            // delete cause it's a duplicate of the last 2 indexes
            timeSplitted.RemoveAt(1);


            //date well organized
            string a = dtp.Value.Month.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Day.ToString() + "/" + dtp.Value.Year.ToString() + " " + timeSplitted[0] + ":" + timeSplitted[1] + " " +
                       timeSplitted[2];

            dt = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
```

dtp =  DateTimePicker

Finally does what I need. Works with day and night shifts. Thanks to all who helped. I will up vote what helped me the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Timespan:

```
var dt1 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0);
var dt2 = new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 13, 0, 0);
var t1 = new TimeSpan(dt2.Ticks - dt1.Ticks);
```

Also you should think about that DateTime is pretty different from TimeSpan. So you should change your design a bit and do not measure work hours in DatTime.

**EDIT:** By the way, DateTime as in the name is point in time. But TimeSpan (again as in the name) is some time span, so you can use DateTime of start and end of some event, but length of this event should be measured in TimeSpan.

**EDIT:** To make TimeSapn correctly work when substracting 11 pm yesterday from 2 am Today, you should specify a Day in DateTime initializer.

Comment: how so? what's wrong with measuring work hours with dateTime?

Comment: DateTime as in the name is point in time. But TimeSpan (as in the name) is some time span, so you can DateTime of start and end of some event, but length of this event should be measured in TimeSpan.

Comment: Oh... That does make sense. You might just solved my problem.

Comment: What is a point of adding PM or AM in a case of time span? Dayshift or nightshift? If it so, you better do it with separate boolean flag. By the way, you can mark an answer as right, SO is all about that.

Comment: Yes, I work day shifts and night shifts. I need to be able to type in from 11:00pm - 1:30am and get 2:30 as a result. How can this be possible?

Comment: You should specify a Day in DateTime: new DateTime(2014, 1, 1, 23, 0, 0); and new DateTime(2014, 1, 2, 2, 30, 0);

Comment: that's the thing, I need to be able to parse it from a textbox.

Comment: DateTime.Parse(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40) or DateTime.ParseExact(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss). Read and learn.

Comment: I used parse, already. But @Arijit Mukherjee told me to try parseExact. I'm trying that out now

Comment: I don't see your input so I don't know what's better fit. If it's user input you better use DateTimePicker or any ither custom control.

Comment: all you have is a textBx and you enter the time you went in, on another textbox you enter the time you went out and you get the result on another txtbox. Pretty simple.

Comment: Why don't use a DateTimePicker, 'cause in any other way you should the correctness of input and you better use DateTime.TryParse or DateTime.TryParseExact.

Comment: After thinking it through and reading the last answer, I think I see what you were trying to tell me all this time lol. I need to set a time or it just goes crazy and gives me a random answer.

Comment: So, any further questions? =))

Comment: I'm trying to make it work with the date picker, but when I parse for time. It works and when I add the info from the date picker, changes the time. If it gets too annoying, I'll sleep and keep working on it tomorrow

Comment: ok I'm getting the value from date picker, and I get the time from a text box. But, here's the new problem. If I use the value from date picker, the time changes to the actual time, if I parse the txtbox for time, the date is changed to the current one. Any way to fix this?

Comment: Need to combine them. Date from first time from second.

Comment: how can I combine them? how can I parse time from a text box and parse date from date picker? and not have one change while parsing the other.

Comment: DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse(a); DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(b); dt1.Hours = dt2.Hours; Try to do something by yourself. I can't write a code for you. You should learn a basic principles of coding.

Comment: I didn't know you could do dt.hours = dt2.hours2. That's very helpful to know

Answer (score 0):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        DateTime tmnext = DateTime.ParseExact(nextdatestring, "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.fff", provider);
        DateTime tmpresent = DateTime.ParseExact(previousdatestring, "yyyyMMdd_HH:mm:ss.fff", provider);
        TimeSpan prevdur = tmnext - tmpresent;
```

Or as suggested by Ehsan Sajjad

`TimeSpan prevdur = tmnext.Subtract(tmpresent);`

I think this is the best work around to convert the string to datetime and get the difference in hours

Comment: But, isn't that the same thing I'm doing? how is it different?

Comment: no its not parse and parse exact gives different value and then timespan gives exact difference

Comment: @user3684831 this is for u

Answer (score 0):

Just see the code below:

```
        DateTime dt1=new DateTime(2000,2,2,23,0,0);
        DateTime dt2=new DateTime(2000,2,3,1,30,0);
        TimeSpan ts = dt2.Subtract(dt1);
```

In this code if you have both date in same day you get 21:30 but if put the dt2 in the day after the difference is 2:30.
I think you need to check it in same day and the day after and then select the smallest value.